# SP Online embedded web page dynamically with dynamic URL parameters

Tags: embedded

We are looking for dynamically constructing the URL for the embedded webpart and I am not able to figure out the sequence of steps (or pseudo code) required for this process.

We have our SP Online website. We have a URL say https://xyz.com?abc=12345&def=67890

We need to create the above URL dynamically with parameters (possibly calling a webservice), and embed the URL into our SP website. I dont know if the javascript can do this for us.

I couldnt find any documentation or articles on the same. Do you have any examples, samples or steps to walk me through?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks